# Spark DataFrame aggregate column values by key into List

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a `DataFrame` that looks like this:

```
+-----------------+-------+
|Id               | value |
+-----------------+-------+
|             1622| 139685|
|             1622| 182118|
|             1622| 127955|
|             3837|3224815|
|             1622| 727761|
|             1622| 155875|
|             3837|1504923|
|             1622| 139684|
+-----------------+-------+
```

And I want to turn it into:

```
    +-----------------+-------------------------------------------+
    |Id               | value                                     |
    +-----------------+-------------------------------------------+
    |             1622|139685,182118,127955,727761,155875,139684  |
    |             3837|3224815,1504923                            |
    +-----------------+-------------------------------------------+
```

Is this possible with `DataFrame` functions only or do I need to convert it to and `RDD`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is possible with the `DataFrame` API. Try:

```
df.groupBy(col("Id"))
  .agg(collect_list(col("value")) as "value")
```

If instead of an `Array` you want a `String` separated by `,`, then try this:

```
df.groupBy(col("Id"))
  .agg(collect_list(col("value")) as "value")
  .withColumn("value", concat_ws(",", col("value")))
```

Comment: Thanks David, awesome!

Comment: what do you import (in standalone app)

Answer (score 0):

As shown by [David Griffin above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37440638/191191), you can use the `collect_list` function from the Scala/Java `DataFrame` API.

However, it is also possible to do it using the same function but with the Spark SQL API:

```
spark.sql("SELECT id, collect_list(value) FROM df GROUP BY id")
```