# Spark dataframe aggregating the values

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Dataframe input

```
+-----------------+-------+
|Id               | value |
+-----------------+-------+
|             1622| 139685|
|             1622| 182118|
|             1622| 127955|
|             3837|3224815|
|             1622| 727761|
|             1622| 155875|
|             3837|1504923|
|             1622| 139684|
|             1453| 536111|
+-----------------+-------+
```

Output:

```
    +-----------------+--------------------------------------------+
    |Id               | value                                      |
    +-----------------+--------------------------------------------+
    |             1622|[139685,182118,127955,727761,155875,139684] |
    |             1453| 536111                                     |
    |             3837|[3224815,1504923]                           |
    +-----------------+--------------------------------------------+
```

When particular `id` is having more than one value then it should collect as `array` format else
it should consider that as a single value `without` brace []

I tried with the below link solution but couldn't able to handle the if-else condition in the data frame.

link: [Spark DataFrame aggregate column values by key into List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37440373/spark-dataframe-aggregate-column-values-by-key-into-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> use Window function

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
scala> var df = Seq((1622, 139685),(1622, 182118),(1622, 127955),(3837,3224815),(1622, 727761),(1622, 155875),(3837,1504923),(1622, 139684),(1453, 536111)).toDF("id","value")

scala> df.show()
+----+-------+
|  id|  value|
+----+-------+
|1622| 139685|
|1622| 182118|
|1622| 127955|
|3837|3224815|
|1622| 727761|
|1622| 155875|
|3837|1504923|
|1622| 139684|
|1453| 536111|
+----+-------+

scala> var df1= df.withColumn("r",count($"id").over(Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("id")).cast("int"))

scala> df1.show()
+----+-------+---+
|  id|  value|  r|
+----+-------+---+
|1453| 536111|  1|
|1622| 139685|  6|
|1622| 182118|  6|
|1622| 127955|  6|
|1622| 727761|  6|
|1622| 155875|  6|
|1622| 139684|  6|
|3837|3224815|  2|
|3837|1504923|  2|
+----+-------+---+
scala> var df2 =df1.selectExpr("*").filter('r ===1).drop("r").union(df1.filter('r =!= 1).groupBy("id").agg(collect_list($"value").cast("string").as("value")))


scala> df2.show(false)
+----+------------------------------------------------+
|id  |value                                           |
+----+------------------------------------------------+
|1453|536111                                          |
|1622|[139685, 182118, 127955, 727761, 155875, 139684]|
|3837|[3224815, 1504923]                              |
+----+------------------------------------------------+
scala> df2.printSchema
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- value: string (nullable = true)
```

let me know if you have any question related to same.

Comment: Thanks, I think you did not understand the problem. if the `id` is having one value then i should not display in the list format. ex: `1453 | [536111]  `

Comment: I'm expecting `1453 | [536111]  ` should be in `1453 | 536111 ` this format

Comment: @Manju, you cannot have several formats in a single column. Here you will have an `ArrayType`

Comment: Can't we store this value `[123,1324]` and `1234` in the string formate? @BlueSheepToken instead of specific datatype formate better to keep in string formate right

Comment: you cannot store data with hybrid datatype

Comment: Ya, I agree with you @MaheshGupta. But can we cast that value to string format? I mean [12, 232] => "[12, 232]" and 12 => "12" ?

Comment: updated Answer have a look. do upvote and accept the answer

Comment: Can you elaborate ```df1.selectExpr("*").filter('r ===1).drop("r").union(df1.filter('r =!= 1).groupBy("id").agg(collect_list($"value").cast("string").as("value")))
``` this statement bit please?

Comment: so basically I am counting the number of occurrence of particular id based on that I am filtering if r is 1 that means it came only once in dataframe and rest is collecting as a list then union

Comment: How about the performance-wise? Since we are using `union`,`Window `, `groupby`, `drop` and `filter`? Will that not be costlier?

Comment: it will of course bcoz you are filtering whole dataset and then performing union.

Comment: This will definitely cost you. Why would you need to have string ? After the collect_list you can convert to string according to the length