# group the data in pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have dataframe like below,

```py
df.select(to_json(struct("items"))).show(1, False)

items
-----
[{ "id":"1","types":{ "0":"1", "price":{ "value":"1"}}},
{ "id":"1","types":{ "0":"2", "price":{ "value":"2"}}},
{ "id":"2","types":{ "0":"3", "price":{ "value":"1"}}}]
```

now I want to achieve the data frame like this in pyspark,
Basically, I want to group the contents based on the id.

```
items
-----
[{ "id":"1","types": [ {"0":"1", "price":{ "value":"1"}}, {"0":"2", "price":{ "value":"2"}} ],
{ "id":"2","types": [ {"0":"3", "price":{ "value":"1"}} ]
```

To reproduce it:

```py
from pyspark.sql import Row

# Spark version: 2.4.4
df = spark.createDataFrame([
 Row(items=[Row(id='1',types=Row(o='1',price=Row(value="1"))),
            Row(id='1',types=Row(o='10',price=Row(value="1"))),
            Row(id='2',types=Row(o='13',price=Row(value="1")))]),
 Row(items=[Row(id='3',types=Row(o='1',price=Row(value="1"))),
            Row(id='4',types=Row(o='10',price=Row(value="1"))),
            Row(id='3',types=Row(o='13',price=Row(value="1")))])
], schema='items:array<struct<id:string,types:struct<`0`:string,price:struct<value:string>>>>')
```

Comment: struct<id:array<struct<0:string,price:struct<value:string> >>> @Kafels

Comment: spark 2.4.4  python2.  @Kafels

Comment: I believe this will solve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37440373/spark-dataframe-aggregate-column-values-by-key-into-list/37440638#37440638

Just get the id and types using the function json_extract  and then aggregate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I used the higher-order function `AGGREGATE` to modify the `items` column to a `map` column type where the key is your `id` and the value is an array of `types` values.

To finish it, I applied another expression to transform from `map` to `struct` type following your desired keys.

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

# It's necessary to run using Spark 3 or later
spark.conf.set('spark.sql.mapKeyDedupPolicy', 'LAST_WIN')


agg_df = df.withColumn('items', f.expr('AGGREGATE(items, CAST(MAP() AS MAP<STRING, ARRAY<STRUCT<`0`:STRING, `price`:STRUCT<`value`:STRING>>>>), (acc, item) -> ' \
                                       'IF(acc[item.id] IS NULL, ' \
                                       'MAP_CONCAT(acc, MAP(item.id, ARRAY(item.types))), ' \
                                       'MAP_CONCAT(acc, MAP(item.id, ARRAY_UNION(acc[item.id], ARRAY(item.types))))))'))

transform_df = agg_df.withColumn('items', f.expr('TRANSFORM(MAP_KEYS(items), key -> STRUCT(key AS id, items[key] AS types))'))

# transform_df.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- items: array (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
#  |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- types: array (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
#  |    |    |    |    |-- 0: string (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |    |    |-- price: struct (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |    |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)

# Databricks only
display(transform_df)
```

Output

[image: display_output]